# Can we get the number of items in the review queues back?

Tags: discussion

Several months ago, SE changed the format of the stuff on the top line.  I got used to the new format, except for one thing:

The old format told me at a glance how many items were in each review queue without my having to click on anything.  I'm not so lazy that I mind (terribly) having to click to see if there is anything to review, but the guilt factor is gone.  If the heading doesn't tell me that there is content to review, I feel much less guilty about skipping the queues.

Can we get the info-at-a-glance back?

Comment: This question is out of scope here.  It a system wide configuration that should be addressed at meta.stackexchange.com There are about [4,000 posts relating to review queues there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=review%20queue) I did not search hard but the topic has probably already been addressed, Voting to close as out of scope.

Comment: @JamesJenkins and others, I understand that this is technically out of scope. However, many people don't even know about SE Meta, much less when and how to search it, especially for a subject that has 4,000 posts! Coming to our own meta with things that so many of our users can relate to doesn't feel necessarily bad, as long as it's not a slippery slope, which I don't think this would be. Rory Alsop was kind enough to get the information and post it, so I personally don't see the harm in letting this be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been covered in [this excellent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/154443) from Jon Ericson.

The change was because of the many issues and complaints about the old system (including that the number was always incorrect)

> Now a red indicator appears
>
> 1. if any review queue has a red dot (explained below) and
> 2. if it’s been at least an hour since you clicked on the review icon.
>
> So the idea is that when you see the indicator light up, it’s a reminder that there are reviews to be done if you haven’t looked recently. The goal is to draw reviewers’ attention to queues that can use some help.
>
> Each queue may be in one of three states:
>
> 1. No dot (empty queue)
> 2. Grey dot (at least one but fewer than N review tasks)
> 3. Red dot (N or more review tasks)
>
> Each review queue has its own threshold (N). The default values are:
>
> ```
> Queue                 Default
> -----          --------------  
> Close                      20
> Reopen                      5
> Low Quality                 4
> Suggested Edits             3
> First Posts                10
> Late Answers                6
> ```

So if you don't see a red dot, there may be review items, but they haven't hit the threshold. This may change your approach to reviewing (I don't know if for better or worse) but it is an SE-wide decision.